# How to display and explode multiple image from db php?

Tags: php, mysql

Im still new to php. I did some research but im unable to find the solution. I wanted to retrieve/display multiple image from db where the image is stored in one column with comas. The code works but Im having problem to display the image (blank). Im not sure where it goes wrong.

Code:

```
 <?php  
                    $sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM studentsubmission where UserId =$user and SubmissionID='1'");
                       
                    foreach ($sql as $key => $row)  {
                        $row['Image_url'] = trim($row['Image_url'],'\,');
                        $temp = explode(',',$row['Image_url'] );
                        print_r($temp);
                        $temp = array_filter($temp);

                        foreach($temp as $image){
                            $images[]="image/".trim( str_replace( array('[',']') ,"" ,$image ) );
                              foreach($images as $image){ ?>
                            
                            
                            <img src="image/<?php echo $image; ?>" width="100px" height="200px"/> 
                            
                             <?php  }  
                           
                        }    
                                               
                          
                     
                 }  ?>
```

Output:
[db table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMqTk.png)

[image blank when run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVNLt.png)

Comment: Also don't get in the habbit of putting multiple values in the same column. Its not how database work. Use a separate table and a `JOIN` to retrieve them.

Comment: @danblack Not necessarily true.  I save multiple image as JSON in a single column.   See my answer below.  JSON is like a  database table with no JOINs necessary.   I also often use JSON instead of a database table.   It's similar to using a memory table for fast processing.   I retrieve the JSON with file_get_contents() and use json_decode() and save it with json_encode() and  file_put_contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image isn't at the URL generated.

Look at the HTML generated, its fine.

Note: look up prepared statements for SQL injection prevention.

Comment: Thanks...Didn't realize that part

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing the the images using JSON. 
To save the image urls:

```
$images = array('url','url','url'); 
$jsn = json_encode($images);
$sql = "UPDATE `table` SET `images` = '$jsn'
mysqli_($link,$sql);
```

To retrieve the image urls:
To minimize SQL Injection I always try to use integer values. So in this case I would use an integer userID.

```
$sql = "SELECT `images` FROM `studentsubmission ` WHERE `userID` = " . intval($user) .  AND `SubmissionID`='1'";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
list($jsn) = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
$images = json_decode($jsn,1);
foreach($images as $key => $image){
  echo "<img src=\"$image\" width=\"100\" height=\"200\" alt=\"image$key\" />\n";
}
```

NOTE: Do not use the px on the width and height.
Always use the alt description. 
Always use tick marks around table and column nanes
Never switch between HTML mode and PHP.
There should only be a `<?php` at the top of the PHP document and `?>` at the bottom.

Instead of switching to HTML use HEREDOC:
You add too much overhead switching back and forth.

```
<?php
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=120');
echo <<<EOT
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><title> Form</title>
<style type="text/css">
</style</head><body>
EOT;

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','user',$password,'db');
ob_flush;    
$sql = "SELECT  `Date`,`Last`,`First`,`DoB`,`address`,`city`,`state`,`zip`,`phone`,`email` FROM `customer` WHERE `id` = $id";
$results = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
list($id,$date,$last,$first,$dob,$address,$city,$state,$zip,$phone,$email) = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_NUM);

echo <<<EOT
<form action="./" method="post">
<br>Last: <br><input type="text" name="last" value="$last"  required />
<br>First: <br><input type="text" name="first" value="$first" required  />
<br>DoB: <br><input type="date" name="dob" value="$dob" required  />

<br><br><div id="add">Address is needed for Insurance<br>and Patient Pay</div>
<br>Address: <br><input name="Address" type="text" value="$address" /><br>
City: <br><input name="city" type="text" value="$city" /><br>
State: (2 character)<br><input name="state" type="text" value="$state" /><br>
Zip: <br><input name="zip" type="text" value="$zip" /><br>
</form>
</body></html>
EOT;
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

I have included a few extra tips that I did not explain.
Feel free to ask.
Every feature I used has a very a very significant impact on page speed performance.
I always score 100% performance and structure on https://gtmetrix.com 
100% on desktop and 98% to 100% mobile at Google's https://pagespeed.web.dev/ 
I have been writing web apps since 1996.  Netscape 1.1 days. There was no MS Explorer back then.